# Is there a way to see a function's closures in FireFox like Chrome can?

Tags: javascript

If I test this code in Chrome's console, I can see in the object [[Scopes]] that the first element is named Closure, and it has the correct names and values of counter's closures. I can't find a way to make this work with FireFox though, or find any other alternative.

```
const counter = (function(increment, offset) {
    let value = offset - increment;
    let firstValue = offset;
    return function() {
        firstValue; // only here for the sake of this demo
        value += increment;
        return value;
    }
})(2, 10);


console.dir(counter); // increment: 2, value: 8, firstValue: 10
counter(); // returns 10
console.dir(counter); // increment: 2, value: 10, firstValue: 10
counter(); // returns 12
console.dir(counter); // increment: 2, value: 12, firstValue: 10
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Every now and then I find it helpful to use console.dir() to debug my functions in case there is a problem with how the closure was created. I usually prefer to work in FireFox and then test in Chrome later on, but sometimes I have to do it the other way around because of this. I prefer FireFox for its CSS tools, and I often use JS to manipulate CSS at runtime.

This particular example isn't really useful except as a demo, since probably not everyone who sees this question knows that you can see closures this way.